# drupal - remove image, content and tags text

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I have just noticed that when viewing an individual node, that the seems to be `Image:`, `Content:` and `Tags:` embedded as a result from the render function. Does any one know how to remove these? (Google turns up nothing, like most Drupal questions)

Regards

EDIT:

Lets say I have a page which loads in taxonomy nodes into a carousel. If I view the page It looks pretty much as intended. If I view each of the nodes individualy /taxonomy/node it appears as:

Image:
[the images]
Content:
[the content]
Tags:
[list of tags]

Same goes if instead of the previous page loading the nodes as they currently do and I do it like so:

```
$ids = taxonomy_select_nodes(array(1));
$professional_nodes = node_load_multiple($ids);
foreach( $professional_nodes as $view ) {
    echo '<li>' . drupal_render(node_view($view) ) . '</li>';
}
```

I get the same outcome.

Comment: Could you explain your case a bit better?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, here is a quick solution

Try to print the teaser version of the nodes, and customize the appearance of the teaser from `manage display` page `admin/structure/types/manage/page/display/teaser`.

You will just need to add `teaser` as a second argument to `node_view` to print the teaser version.

```
$ids = taxonomy_select_nodes(array(1));
$professional_nodes = node_load_multiple($ids);
foreach( $professional_nodes as $view ) {
    echo '<li>' . drupal_render(node_view($view, "teaser")) . '</li>'; // the edited line.
}
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.